# How to dynamically create FromGroup from an observable?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I am creating this page that suppose to contain multiple reactive froms (for each country for example). These forms should be create base on the the json array i get from the back end so user can see what the current setting is and update individually. Since i dont know how many of these data set i will be getting, I created one main form and a FormArray for each data set i get. However, if i use FormArray when one of the field is flagged as invalid by the form validators, the whole form is flagged as invalid (all the FormArray nested forms).

I have also tried to create different forms for each data set inside the observable, but it give me the following error

```
TS2339: Property 'countryForm' does not exist on type 'CountryComponent'.
```

so here is my TS

```
export class CountryComponentimplements OnInit {

// Form
countryForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.GetCountryDef();
  }

 GetCountryDef() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    this.http.get(`https://api_call`).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {

        // Form
        const CountryArray = new FormArray(data.map(item => new FormGroup({
          country: new FormControl(item.country, Validators.required),
          population: new FormControl(item.population, Validators.pattern(/\-?\d*\.?\d{1,5}/)),
          GPD: new FormControl(item.GPD, Validators.pattern(/\-?\d*\.?\d{1,5}/))
          .......
        }),
      ));

        this.countryForm= this.fb.group({
          country: CountryArray ,
        });

      this.spinner.hide();
      }

      );
 }
```

My html

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let country; let i = index">  
            <form style="width: inherit;" [formGroup]="countryForm">
                <div formArrayName="country">
                    <div formGroupName={{i}}>
                        <label >populcation:</label> 
                        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="population">

                        <label >GPD:</label>  
                        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="GPD">
.......
            </form>
          </td>
```

So my questions is how can i dynamically create FromGroup from an observable or how can i make the validator only flag the error for one FormArray?

===============================================================================
@ AJT_82 I have tried that, but the form is not showing even after it is loaded.

So i have changed it to

```
   export class CountryComponentimplements OnInit {
   // Form
   //countryForm: FormGroup;
```

and

```
   let countryForm: FormGroup; // Will change to to different form for each country after
    countryForm= this.fb.group({
      country: CountryArray ,
    });
```

and it give me the same error

```
TS2339: Property 'countryForm' does not exist on type 'CountryComponent'.
```

Comment: This http-request is asynchronous, so your template is rendered before form has been built. One option is to put an `*ngIf="countryForm"` on your element.

Comment: @ AJT_82 I have tried that, but the form is not showing even after it is loaded. 

So i have changed it to 

       export class CountryComponentimplements OnInit {
       // Form
       //countryForm: FormGroup;

and
       
       let countryForm: FormGroup;
        countryForm= this.fb.group({
          country: CountryArray ,
        });


and i give me the same error

TS2339: Property 'countryForm' does not exist on type 'CountryComponent'.

Comment: Okay, could you create a demo demonstrating this issue, much easier to help :)

Answer (score 0):

User, Are you using mat-table? Mat table work feed by an array, it's true that the array can be an array of FormControls but it's hard work with an array of Form Controls.

mat-table expect you feed with some like

```
[{country:new FormControl(),population:new FormControl(),GDP:new FormControl()},
 {country:new FormControl(),population:new FormControl(),GDP:new FormControl()},
 {country:new FormControl(),population:new FormControl(),GDP:new FormControl()}
...]
```

Instead of this, you can make a normal table with an array

```
    <table >
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th >Country</th>
                <th >Population</th>
                <th >GDP</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngIf="formArray" [formGroup]="formArray">
            <tr  *ngFor="let item of formArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <td ><input formControlName="country"></td>
                <td ><input formControlName="population"></td>
                <td ><input formControlName="GDP"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

where I prefer refer to the array itself.

If we inject FormBuilder in the constructor

```
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}
```

our formArray can be former like:

```
  this.formArray=new FormArray(data.map(item=>{
    return this.fb.group({
      country:item.position,
      population:item.name,
      GDP:item.weight
    })
  }));
```

Comment: Yes, i am using a mat-table, I will to try to use a regular table tmr. But i am not too sure it solves the issue. if i have an invalid input in the 2nd array in the FormArray, wouldn't it still mark the whole form including other forms in the FormArry as invalid? I guess i shouldnt try to process each form in the formarry individually

Comment: User, if any field of one Form is invalid, all the form are invalid but is the control who has the "validator" (really you can make a validator over a FormGroup or over the whole form too). When a input is invalid Angular add the class ng-invalid to the input (and only to the input) the class ng-invalid see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes. If you want to use a ngIf to show the error you can do < div *ngIf="formArray.controls[i].country.isInvalid" >error< /div>